# How to convert a string JSON with HTML tags and display it in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

```json
    [{
    "id": "services.html",
    "img": "img/SolutionInnerbananer.jpg",
    "p2": "If it was intrested you can buy it <a class="product1">Buy Now</a>"
    }]
```

I need to add some HTML tags into a JSON file and display it into my component,
I use JSON file and import it into my tsx file but I get string output
Is their any solution please?

Comment: looks like you want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute with your data.

```js
return (
  <>
    {data.map((d) => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: d.p2 }}/>)}
  </>
)
```